# java- jsf library that has good mobile browser support

Tags: java, jsf

I am looking to create a simple mobile web app, and I am considering a good jsf(Java server faces) library for this purpose.

Which JSF libraries do you recommend? I am looking for something that

(a) Has good support for atleast android/iphone/blackberry/windows mobile devices.
(b) Easy to create new mobile skins. (This is very important!)
(c) Same codebase works when web app is accessed from a pc.

Answer (score 2):

I used Primefaces for a web app sometimes back. They've a mobile version of the library, which from the demos, seems great. Try it out at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/mobile/index.jsf.